# php get value from textarea

Tags: php, parsing, textarea

how can i get value from field textarea. i want to detail- i need to parse html page and get value from field textarea not call something like $_POST["textarea"]

Comment: $_POST['textarea'] is how you get data from a submitted textarea. Why do you not want to use this method?

Comment: I think he wants to parse the existing HTML structure and get the `value` attribute from it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**

Best way for parsing like this is to use DOM, http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php
After you load your page into the DOM, you can use `getElementById('textarea_id')`, [php docs are here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php). If your text area has ID or `getElementsByTagName('textarea')`, but in this case you will get NodeList. So it will look something like this:

```
// dom
$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('textarea');
$node1 = $nodes->item(0);
```

**Option 2**

Another option is to get the page as string and use [regular expression](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to match your textbox and get info out of it. I found this class in google, it is HTML Form Parser - http://www.alexandruion.com/html-form-parser

Answer (score 0):

It's much simpler, but this should work (assuming you print $display later on)

```
$display .= "<textarea name='notes' rows='3' cols='30'>".$notes."</textarea><br />";
```

Answer (score 0):

This didn't work for me:

```
// dom
$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('textarea');
$node1 = $nodes->item(0);
```

I used **`$node1 = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;`** since the class DOMElement inherit the DOMNode properties [as you can see here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php).